# Android studio gradle error?

Tags: android, gradle

My android studio project suddenly give gradle error. I add only one xml file and one Activity and suddenly give this error.

> Gradle: Error parsing XML: XML or text declaration not at start of
>   entity
>
> Gradle: Error while executing aapt command
>
> Gradle: Execution failed for task ':TJOD:processDebugResources'.

please look at image for sample view;

http://www.tjod.org/questions/error.jpg

Comment: The image is corrupted. And your XML probably is as well. Show us the XML file.

Comment: Check your xml files, if there are some errors.

Comment: I fixed image. Please look again. Whixh to xml file show you. I have one more XML file. Androidmanifest ?

Comment: This is my res folder View  http://www.tjod.org/questions/res-folder.png

Comment: you have to check res folder under src/main/res (not under build folder).
Check if any xml file contains some errors.

Comment: All xml file give error. it was suddenly :(

Comment: please run gradle from command line with switches `--info` and `--stacktrace`. This will give you more detaile error info. If you will not resolve this issue then, please post gradle outpute here.